# event listener: when to apply css to dynamic content

Tags: javascript, css

needing to apply CSS to event.listener-generated content.

In my nav/filter menu, I click an item and the event listener generates a new dynamically populated nav menu/filter.  It functions as necessary but I need to add css to the items that were clicked on to trigger the listener's output.

should it be added, as I build the html output
here, for example.

```
dataset += "<p>"
           + "<input type="checkbox" 
id="sub_category:"+underscored_v+ "/>"+"<label 
for="sub_category:"+underscored_v+">"+v+"</label>"+"</p>";
```

or should I do it in this code (you'll see my attempt at the bottom):

```
function update_secondary_filters(opts) {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/php-queries/product-filter-secondary-query.php",

    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: {
      filterOpts: opts
    },
    success: function(records) {
      //console.log(records);
      //alert('SUCCESS!');
      // alert(records);
      $('#filtering_div').html(makeSecondaryFilter(records));
    }
  });
  // make the filter heading button show as active 
  var clicker = function() {
    $('sub_category:premium').each(function() {
      this.checked = true;
    });

  }
  clicker();
}
```

Comment: Why do you have backslashes before all the `$`?

Comment: And other stray backslashes in the code?

Comment: I don't see any CSS anywhere, what are you asking about.

Comment: Backslashes are to satisfy the perl interpreter.  I want the checkboxes in the returned code to be assigned the status of 'checked'. I'll remove the backslashes so it'll be easier to read.

Comment: Checkbox status isn't CSS, it's a DOM property, although you can have CSS styling that depends on it. Anyway, you do it wherever it makes the most sense. If you know whether the box should be checked when you're generating the HTML, do it there. If it's determined dynamically at runtime, do it in JS.

Comment: Thank you.  After a break I recalled it was the checked=checked value that I could put into the html output.  Pleased to learn it didn;t require a JS snippet. :thumbsup: